# Return Earliest Date based on value within dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with REIGN data that documents elections and leaders in countries around the world (https://www.oneearthfuture.org/datasets/reign)

In the dataset there is an boolean election anticipation variable that turns from 0 to 1 to denote that an election is anticipated in at least the next 6 months, possibly sooner.

[Excel sheet of data in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pPe7.png)

I want to create a new column that returns the earliest date of when anticipation (column N) turns 1 (i.e. when was the election first anticipated).

So for example, with Afghanistan in column we have an election in 2014 and in 2017.
In column N we see it turn from 0 to 1 on Oct, 2014 (election anticipated) and then we see it go back to 0 on July, 2014 (election concluded) until it goes back to 1 on Jan, 2019 (election anticipated) and then turns back to 0 on Oct, 2019.

So if successful, I would capture Oct, 2014 (election anticipated) and Jan, 2019 (election anticipated) as election announcement dates in a new column along with any other dates an election was anticipated.

Currently I have the following:

```py
#bringing in Reign CSV
regin = pd.read_csv('REIGN_2021_7(1).csv')

#shows us the first 5 rows to make sure they look good
print(regin.head())

#show us the rows and columns in the file
regin.shape

#Getting our index
print(regin.columns)

#adding in a date column that concatenates year and month
regin['date'] = pd.to_datetime(regin[['year', 'month']].assign(DAY=1))
regin.head

#def conditions(s):
    if (s['anticipation'] == 1):
        return (s['date'])
    else:
        return 0
    
regin['announced_date'] = regin.apply(conditions, axis=1)

print(regin.head)
```

Biggest issue for me is that while this returns the date of when a 1 appears, it does not display the earliest date. How I can loop through the anticipation column and return the minimum date, but do so multiple times as a country will have many elections over the years and there are therefore multiple instances in column N for one country of the anticipation turning on(1) and off(0).

Thanks in advance for any assistance! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you can loop over your dates, you will probably want to use the `datetime` module (assuming all dates have the same format):

```
from datetime import datetime
[...]
earliest_date = datetime.today()
[... loop over data, by country ...]
  date1 = datetime.strptime(input_date_string1, date_string_format)
  if date1 < earliest_date:
    earliest_date = date1
[...]
```

This module supports (among other things):

- parsing date objects from a string (`.strptime(in_str, format)`)
- comparison of date objects (`date1 > date2`)
- datetime object from current date + time (`.today()`)
- datetime object from arbitrary date (`.date(year, month, day)`)

docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html